# Limits of $s(x)$ and $H(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is $s(x) = \sin x$ and $$H(x) = \frac{(x+6)(x+7)}{(x+6) (x^2 - 8x +14)}$$

I'm looking for the value of $x$ where it discontinuous.

Answer (score 1):

To determine discontinuity, find values that make the function undefined or $0/0$:

- For $f(x) = \sin x$, there are no values for which f(x) is undefined, so it is continuous everywhere.
- For $\frac{(x+6)(x+7)}{(x+6)(x^2 - 8x +14)}$, analyze the denominator because division by 0 makes the function undefined at that point. Also, know that the function may or may not be reduced, so always reduced to lowest terms. Therefore, our fraction becomes: $\frac{x+7}{x^2 - 8x +14}$ Now we analyze our denominator, $x^2 -8x + 14$, and solve for 0.

Using the quadratic formula:

$$x = \frac{8 \pm \sqrt{64 -56}}{2}$$
$$x = \frac{8 \pm \sqrt{8}}{2}$$
$$x = \frac{8 \pm 2\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
$$x = 4 + \sqrt{2},\ 4 - \sqrt{2}$$

Your function is discontinuous at these points.

**Please note that at x = -6, the function $f(x)$ yields 0/0. This is a type of discontinuity called a hole. Read [this](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/grphrtnl4.htm) for more info**

Comment: Well you can't reduce the fraction if $x=-6$.

Comment: @Hakim, x = -6 is what we define as a hole. It is a point where f(x) isn't continuous. I understand my error now. Will update

Answer (score 0):

$x\mapsto\sin x$ is continuous everywhere, and for $x\mapsto\tfrac{(x+6)(x+7)}{(x+6)(x^2-8x+14)}$ it is discontinuous when the denominator $=0$. So you'll have to solve the equation $$(x+6)(x^2-8x+14)=0.$$

Comment: can i put -6 for x? but it think it will just cancel out from the numerator so I was solving (x+7) / (x^2 - 8x +14)

Comment: @Mike You can't cancel out $(x+6)$ since when $x=-6$ you'll have $0/0$.

Comment: so -6 is right? then just substitute it? sorry if i suck. I had my math lessons 2 years ago

Comment: @Mike Yes, the function is discontinuous at $-6$, so you just have to see when $(x^2-8x+14)=0$ to see if there are other points where the function is discontinuous.

Comment: I think it's just -6? I try to put in number 1 to 9 in (x^2 - 8x +14) with x but i still end up with a number and thank you very much hakim

Comment: @Mike No, there are more numbers for which the function is discontinuous. Do you know how to solve $x^2-8x+14=0$?

Comment: No.. besides the comment above by quadratic formula

Comment: @Mike Well if you have an equation of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$ where $a\neq0$ then its solution is given by: $$x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$ Here you have $a=1,b=-8,c=14$. So just plug in those numbers in the formula and it will give you the solutions.

Comment: got it thanks so -6, 4+ square root of 2 and 4- square root of 2 would be my answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Mike You're welcome, glad I could help! $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$